# How to add image to our site with extension .php

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents, readfile

Sorry if it's stupid question. I seeing on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) can do like this.[image: this]

I do like this

```
$imagepath="smile.jpg";

$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);
$imgheight=imagesy($image);
$color=imagecolorallocate($image,0, 153, 51);
imagestring($image, 20, 50, $imgheight-30, "this is testing", $color);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

My code can show image on browser and when I element to inspect it's show it's called in extensions .php right as i wish but I can not add text or style or anything on it.

For example, I just add more code like this

```
<div style="height: 600px;width: 100%; position: relative; border:1px solid red">
<div>
    <?php echo "Hello text"; ?>
</div>
<div style=" float: left;height: 600px;margin: 0 auto;border:1px solid yellow">
    <?php
        $imagepath="smile.jpg";
        $image=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);
        $imgheight=imagesy($image);
        $color=imagecolorallocate($image,0, 153, 51);
        imagestring($image, 20, 50, $imgheight-30, "this is testing", $color);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

it's show [image]

anyone can help me this problem

thanks

Comment: "*but I can not add text or style or anything on it.*", what do you mean?

Comment: I think he means that the page doesn't support anything else but the picture itself. Which is because of the header type @pov is using ^^

Comment: content on browser have only image, I want add text or style and anything as normal page

Comment: Maybe post the html and css code too? So we can follow what you're trying to do

Comment: You can serve an image with PHP but you have to just serve the image. You can't make a rendered HTML page appear as an image.

Comment: @M1ke Yes, this is problem but I want solutions

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by rendering a page as an image? You can generate images in PHP or server images via PHP. Why do you need to have a rendered HTML page appear as an image?

Comment: @BartScheffer  see my edited

Comment: @M1ke I want simple page have image and content text as our page in any site, Example on http://php.net/ that my image show in extension .php

Answer (score 0):

you have to put php code into another file and add an exit instruction and put header instruction at begin like this :

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); //Before every instruction
$imagepath="smile.jpg";

$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);
$imgheight=imagesy($image);
$color=imagecolorallocate($image,0, 153, 51);
imagestring($image, 20, 50, $imgheight-30, "this is testing", $color);

imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);

exit; // You have to add exit instruction to escape rendered attempt
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to serve an image from PHP is this. This will work but you won't be able to make any changes to the image within the code itself.

*However* this *would* allow you to carry out other actions on your server, e.g. logging to a file or database that the image was viewed.

```
$image = file_get_contents('/path/to/image/.jpg');
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $image;
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that your image code does not work inlined in the html is because of the header

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

You can only set headers before any content is served (in your case you `echo` html before the `header()` which makes it fail.
Refering to an image rendered by php can only be done by using a separate php file for the image and refer to the file with `<img src="file.php">`.

I understand that you want to add some text as well, but the text is not part of an image and cannot be served using these headers. For the text to be in or below the image you need to alter the image itself.

To edit images using php check the page here for some usefull functions: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I think like this too, because my page is  `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`  so can not content text that why i post this question for find solution that I need, I want to know how page http://php.net/  can do it

Comment: php.net doesnt render text. It is just an image of the text php.

Comment: in my question or you can inspect element to on logo of `php.net` it's image but and show `<img src="/images/logo.php" width="48" height="24" alt="php">` i want do like this site too